# Can't use onDismiss() when using custom dialogs - Android

Tags: android, dialog, custom-controls

I'm working on a little program, and I need to add a custom dialog that passes some info to the calling acitivity when it closes.
I extended the dialog class, and when I try to capture the custom dialog when it closes,using an onDismiss listener, it never reaches it because I used a custom dialog.

This is part of my activity -

```
    .
    .
    .
       attributes customizeDialog = new attributes(con,position,pick.getLastVisiblePosition());
        customizeDialog.show();
```

(The attributes being the name of the class that extends the dialog class).

Here is the event listener I set up when the dialog finishes -

```
    customizeDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            Log.v("LOG_CAT",attributes.selectedIndexes.get(0) + " " + attributes.selectedIndexes.get(1) + " " + attributes.selectedIndexes.get(2) + " " + attributes.selectedIndexes.get(3) + " " + attributes.selectedIndexes.get(5) + " ");
    }

});
```

I know i'm doing it wrong,I just don't know how to fix it.

I would really appreciate any help with this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you missing a call to a super method somewhere in your custom dialog class?  That is the usual culprit when an event you are expecting on a custom class doesn't happen.

Comment: Hey Tofira I used the same code you used and it works fine. Maybe you missed something else?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I tend to have my activity implement listeners like this...

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
    implements DialogInterface.OnDismissListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        attributes customizeDialog = new attributes(con,position,pick.getLastVisiblePosition());
        customizeDialog.setOnDismissListener(this);
        customizeDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // Do whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think it should be DialogInterface.OnDismissListener

Comment: @TRonZ : Ooops yes, that was a typo. Funny it's taken nearly a year and a half for someone to spot that. I'll correct it.

Comment: Actually I was trying to implement your code in my app , thats why I figured it out .

Answer (score 5):

You could have your calling activity implement a custom listener interface that is called when the dialog closes:

```
public interface MyDialogListener {
    void OnCloseDialog();
}

public class MyActivity implements MyDialogListener {
    public void SomeMethod() {
        MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog(this, this);
        myDialog.show();
    }

    public void OnCloseDialog() {
        // Do whatever you want to do on close here
    }

}

public class MyDialog extends Dialog {
    MyDialogListener mListener;

    public MyDialog (Context context, MyDialogListener listener) {
        super(context, R.style.Dialog);
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.CloseButton:
                mListener.OnCloseDialog();
                dismiss()
                break;
            default:
                //...
        }
    }
}
```

This is especially useful if you want to send stuff back to the caller at any other time besides on dismissal.

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to have some sort of saving inside the dialog, again, you have to use `onDicmissListener` since for custom dialogs `onDismiss` is not called by default:

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog implements DialogInterface.OnDismissListener {

    public CustomDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setupLayout(context);
    }

    public CustomDialog(Context context, int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
        setupLayout(context);
    }

    protected CustomDialog(Context context, boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
        super(context, cancelable, cancelListener);
        setupLayout(context);
    }

    private void setupLayout(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
        getWindow().setAttributes(params);

        setOnDismissListener(this);

        loadPreferences();
    }

    private void loadPreferences() {
      // ...
    }

    private void savePreferences() {
       // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
        savePreferences();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using custom dialog and can't dismiss it, try below code.
It worked for me.

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }, 1500);
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to remember is that an `OnDismissListener` is listening for the dismiss of the child processes.  The parent of your customer dialog needs the `onDismissListener`, not the dialog itself.

"Interface used to allow the creator of a dialog to run some code when the dialog is dismissed."

Answer (score 0):

To add dialog inside CustomDialog class:

```
public class MessageBoxDialog extends Dialog implements DialogInterface.OnDismissListener
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         ...
         setOnDismissListener(this);
         ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {

    }
}
```