# Android reloading a webView

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an app, which has a listener that verifies internet connectivity. So whenever the internet connectivity changes (it is down), it alerts the user.

Now on the main activity of the app, I have a webView, which is loaded in `onResume()`. But, if the user forgets to turn on the internet, when the user enters the app, the alert dialog telling him this appears, and obviously, the vebView is not loaded.

My problem is that I can't find a way to make the loading of the vebView happened, after the user enables the internet and closes the alert dialog.

Basically I would need to call again the `onResume()` method...or another solution would be to have a refresh button be displayed in the place where the vewView should be...but I couldn't find something similar to `setEmptyView` for webView...

Any ideas guys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found a simple answer to my problem called : `DialogInterface.OnDismissListener`.

Basically this is an interface, that has a method `onDismiss()`. I have created a class where my alert dialogs are created, and all the activities extend this class, and also I have implemented `onDismiss()` in it like this :

```
 @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        onResume();

    }
```

More info :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener.html

[Can't use onDismiss() when using custom dialogs - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916654/cant-use-ondismiss-when-using-custom-dialogs-android)

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by listening for changes in connectivity using:

```
<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
```

See [this page](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html) for more information.

Comment: the problem isn't the status of the internet...is how to reload the webView after i have internet again

Comment: You use the action to determine when connection is back and call the reloading method when this happens. You might need to refactor the refresh code out of your `onResume()` method.

Comment: i didn't specify that i was a beginner in android..so maybe you can show me some code or example to accomplish that?    I'm open to the second solution, that as i said involves a refresh button appearing if the webView is not loaded..if you also know how to do it.  And maybe after i can see which one is easier to implement for me :)