# How to listen to a DialogFragment dismiss event

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I've implemented a custom DialogFragment which I'm showing it on a RatingBar rating listener event in my postReviewFragment, I want to set my RatingBar rating back to 0 when the dialog is dismissed by the user.

Searching on SO I've come across these threads but the solutions doesn't seem to work for me :

[DialogFragment Close Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163520/dialogfragment-close-event)

[Can't use onDismiss() when using custom dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916654/cant-use-ondismiss-when-using-custom-dialogs-android)

[DialogFragment and onDismiss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786033/dialogfragment-and-ondismiss?noredirect=1&lq=1)

What I've tried so far using above threads :

Implementing `DialogInterface.OnDismissListener` on the postReviewFragment and overriding `onDismiss()` method

```
   @Override
    public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {

        userRating.setRating(0);

    }
```

Also in the DialogFragment I've overide the `onDismiss()` method

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    final Fragment parentFragment = getParentFragment();
    if (parentFragment instanceof DialogInterface.OnDismissListener) {
        ((DialogInterface.OnDismissListener) parentFragment).onDismiss(dialog);
    }
}
```

But still the `onDismiss()` method does not fire up when the dialogFragment is dismissed, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I managed to figure it out :

1. First of all make sure you've implemented `DialogInterface.OnDismissListener` and overriden onDismiss() method on both DialogFragment and the Fragment showing the dialog.
2. Then when you show the DialogFragment set a target fragment, here I pass the rating via a Bundle to the DialogFragment

   ```
   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
               PostReviewDialogFragment dialog = new PostReviewDialogFragment();

               // optionally pass arguments to the dialog fragment
               Bundle args = new Bundle();
               args.putInt("usersRating", rating);
               dialog.setArguments(args);

               dialog.setTargetFragment(RestaurantReviewFragment.this,REVIEW_FRAGMENT);


               dialog.show(fm, TAG);
   ```
3. On DialogFraments's `onDismiss()` method I set the rating to  0 and add it to an intent extra and set ratingbar in dialogFragment to user selected value.

   ```
   Intent i = new Intent()
           .putExtra("rating1", rating);
   getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
   ```
4. Then I override `onActivityResult()` method to read the values and set ratingbar value on the fragment to 0 when dismissed.

This maybe not the best approach but it works, I will update answer if I find anything better than this method. Apologize if my explanation isn't very clear, check out below thread for more detailed explanation.

References :  [How to send data from DialogFragment to a Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19677039/5208124)

Answer (score -1):

Use the available [OnDismissListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener).

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: This is dangerous as it overrides the DialogFragments internal dismiss listener